# Combine multiple dataframes into dataframe of multi-index columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Suppose I have 3 dataframes,

`df_1` representing revenues

```
Year        TSLA    MSFT     AVY
2019         851     200   112.8
2018         725     150    92.6
```

`df_2` representing some other revenues

```
Year        TSLA    MSFT     AVY
2019          10      13      17
2018          11      14      18
```

and `df_3` representing expenses

```
Year        TSLA    MSFT     AVY
2019         110     213     317
2018         111     214     418
```

what might the code be to obtain the following df?

```
       TSLA                             MSFT                             AVY
Year   revenues other_revenues expenses revenues other_revenues expenses revenues other_revenues expenses
2019        851             10      110      200             13      213    112.8             17      317
2018        725             11      111      150             14      214     92.6             18      418
```

where the columns are in multi-index form?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) and [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) for sorting `MultiIndex`:

```
#if not Year is index first create it
L = [x.set_index('Year') for x in [df_1, df_2, df_3]]
df = (pd.concat(L, 
               axis=1, 
               keys=('revenues', 'other_revenues', 'expenses'))
        .swaplevel(1, 0, axis=1)
        .sort_index(axis=1))
print (df)
         AVY                            MSFT                            TSLA  \
     revenues expenses other_revenues revenues expenses other_revenues revenues   
Year                                                                           
2019   112.8      317             17     200      213             13     851   
2018    92.6      418             18     150      214             14     725   

                              
     expenses other_revenues  
Year                          
2019      110             10  
2018      111             11
```

EDIT: For order like in original add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) from unique values of first level of `MultiIndex`:

```
sub = ['revenues', 'other_revenues', 'expenses']
L = [x.set_index('Year') for x in [df_1, df_2, df_3]]
df = (pd.concat(L, 
               axis=1, 
               keys=sub)
        .swaplevel(1, 0, axis=1))

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns.levels[0], sub])
df = df.reindex(mux, axis=1)
        
print (df)
         TSLA                             MSFT                          \
     revenues other_revenues expenses revenues other_revenues expenses   
Year                                                                     
2019      851             10      110      200             13      213   
2018      725             11      111      150             14      214   

          AVY                          
     revenues other_revenues expenses  
Year                                   
2019    112.8             17      317  
2018     92.6             18      418
```

Comment: Is there a mistake with swaplevel and sort index, after keys?

Comment: @finmathstudent - ya, it was missing one `'`, sorry.

Comment: What would the code be if I want to specify the order ('revenues', 'other_revenues', expenses') for the inner level column index? Rather than the sort you chose?

Comment: @finmathstudent - Give me a sec.